# TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object

Tags: customer-session, phpunit, magento2.4.5p1

I upgraded my website from magento 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1,

When i run php unit test case for my custom module(This module overides the CreatePassword.php file from Customer module) throws error from Session manager like below

TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object

/var/www/html/project/Vendor_Name/src/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:151
/var/www/html/project/Vendor_Name/src/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePassword.php:100

Comment: which php version you are using?

Comment: PHP version is 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause of Issue :**

vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php:151
[image: SessionManager.php:151]

First array member is $this->storage which would be null and hence you would be getting the error that it is not a valid class name or object.

vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePassword.php:100
[image: CreatePassword.php:100]

When it tries to get rp_customer_id value using the getRpCustomerId method,
__call method of SessionManager gets called to fetch data from session storage. It wouldn't work with PHPUnit Test as the storage will be null.

**How to fix the issue :**
Need to create mock object of Customer Session Model and set the return value for getRpCustomerId method. Hence, it will fetch the data from the mock.

> Create Mock of \Magento\Customer\Model\Session class

```
$this->sessionMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Session::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['getRpCustomerId'])
    ->getMock();
```

> Set return value for getRpCustomerId

```
$this->sessionMock->expects($this->once())
   ->method('getRpCustomerId')
   ->willReturn('123');
```